# How to Hash password for prestashop

Tags: android, prestashop

i'm working on a Android Project for Prestashop.
I see in the API that it is possible to obtain customers using Prestashop's Webservice but I see that password is hashed.
I want to ask you what i have to do to hash password from my Android client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the value of the _COOKIE_KEY_ constant from config/settings.inc.php

The hashed password is actually MD5 of the concatenation of the _COOKIE_KEY_ with the actual password. So in PHP it looks like:

```
md5(_COOKIE_KEY_.'customer actual password');
```

Comment: I tried to use this function in my REST api but it doesn't work.
I solved importing settings.inc.php and using function Tools::encrypt().

Comment: The function Tools::encrypt() just returns the result of the code that I've provided.